# Pytorch tensor representing a 3D grid with color values

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, torch

Given a list of density values (scalars) that represent the density of an X,Y,Z coordinate on a 3D grid, how would I create a single tensor that can store this information?

i.e. a tensor that has dimensions of 1x20x20x20 for example would represent a 20x20x20 grid such that:

```
print(tensor[:,x1,y1,z1])
0.6

print(tensor[:,x2,y2,z2])
0.4
```

Comment: So you want to convert a `1x20*20*20` tensor into a `1x20x20x20` tensor?

Comment: I want a 1x20x20x20 tensor where the 1st dimension values are my custom values rather than random ones.

Comment: If I have XYZ coordinates for a 20x20x20 grid, and corresponding values for each coordinate, how would I create a tensor of shape 1x20x20x20 with my values

Comment: But how is your input data layed out, is a 1D tensor with all values for each XYZ point or is it a 3D tensor, in which case why would you want to turn it into a 4D tensor?

Comment: Currently it's a 1D tensor with each index corresponding to a 3D point in a 20x20x20 grid, meaning the length of the tensor is 8,000. It simply holds scalars representing the density of each xyz coordinate. 

I want to transform it into a tensor of shape 1x20x20x20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you would like to turn a `(2000)` 1D-tensor into a `(1x20x20x20)` 4D-tensor.

Assuiming you have your initial tensor layed out as something like:

```
X = torch.tensor([111,112,113,121,122,123,131,132,133,211,212,213,221,222,223,231,232,233,311,312,313,321,322,323,331,332,333])
```

This is as simple as using view on it:

```
xyz = X.view(3, 3, 3, 1)
```

And, `X[0, 1, 2]` will give you *`[123]`* as expected.